# Setting xlink:href to a local file to create an <image> element in SVG not showing

Tags: jquery, svg, xml-namespaces, setattribute, xlink

```html
<div id="vmap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <svg height="600" width="800">
    <image xlink:href="file://deutschland_hr_relief.png" width="800" height="600" y="0" x="0"></image>
    <g transform="scale(0.7490636704119851) translate(237.99999999999997, 0)">
    <path>
//pathdata
</path></g></svg></div>
```

The HTML code is created with an jquery script. The image I want to include is local in the same directory. I tried to give xlink:href the absolute path(prefixed with file:///) and with and without , it does not work. I am absolutely sure that path and filename are correct. Running on Xubunutu 14.04 + Firefox(up to date).

What could be the reason ?

Solved thanks to Robert Longson.

created image with

```html
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
this.bg_image.setAttributeNS(null,'x','0');
    this.bg_image.setAttributeNS(null,'y','0');
    this.bg_image.setAttributeNS(null,'height',this.height);
    this.bg_image.setAttributeNS(null,'width',this.width);

    this.bg_image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",'xlink:href','deutschland_hr_relief.png');
```

Comment: Did you try just setting the path as `/deutschland_hr_relief.png`?

Comment: yes. that, with the slash and without.

Comment: I somewhat suspected the svg might simply overpaint the background, but I played around with opacity settings in the svg and it does not show up.

Comment: The image does show up normally when inside a normal IMG tag as src.

Comment: jquery can't create link:href attributes properly. You need to use setAttributeNS.

Answer (score -1):

Use `createAttributeNS` to create an `xlink:href` attribute, and `setAttributeNode` to set it. For example:

```js
  var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
  var attr = document.createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href');
  attr.value = 'http://example.com';
  anchor.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

```html
     <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="60">
       <svg:g style="fill:#3399cc; font-size:36pt; font-weight: bold">
         <svg:a id="anchor">
           <svg:text x="50%" y="65%" text-anchor="middle">example.com</svg:text>
         </svg:a>
       </svg:g>
     </svg:svg>
```

**References**

- [MicroSyntax Descriptions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MicrosyntaxDescriptions)
- [Thirteen ways to deploy SVG on the Web: Start Chopping Off Heads](http://www.codedread.com/blog/archives/2010/09/21/start-chopping-off-heads/)